# bash: "${A:-B}" operator

Tags: bash, operators

I've been refactoring some bash code, and stumbled upon this bash notation:

```
"${string_a:-string_b}"
```

I've played a little with this on the command line:

```
$ echo "${string_a:-string_b}"
string_b
$ export string_a=string_a_value
$ echo "${string_a:-string_b}"
string_a_value
```

I seems that the `{a:-b}` notation returns the value of *variable* `a` if it is defined, or the *string* `b` otherwise.

Where can I find a more formal definition for this operator?

Comment: I like this reference card: http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/refcards.html # Table B-4. Parameter Substitution and Expansion

Comment: @fedorqui your comment answers the question `Where can I find a more formal definition for this operator?`, I think it could go to answer.

Comment: Seemed to be so short info for an answer, but I just did it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Peer pressure, I post my comment as an answer : )

I like this reference card: [Advanced Bash-Scripting Guide](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/refcards.html) , specifically in your case it will be useful *"# Table B-4. Parameter Substitution and Expansion"*.

I do not copy any issue they indicate not to violate any copyright. Just find all information there.

Answer (score 3):

Another useful link is the [Shell Parameter Expansion section](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Shell-Parameter-Expansion) in the Bash Reference 
Manual. The `:-` operator is defined as:

> ${parameter:-word} If parameter is unset or null, the expansion of
>   word is substituted. Otherwise, the value of parameter is substituted.

By the way, bash features three similar operators `${parameter:=word}`, `${parameter:?word}` and `${parameter:+word}`, defined in that section.

Answer (score 2):

You can access bash documentation using [man bash](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html). To search type `/`

> ${parameter:-word}
>
> > Use Default Values.  If *parameter* is unset or null, the expansion of *word* is substituted.  Otherwise, the value of *parameter* is substituted.

Comment: Funny that this operator ha no name.